# Why does this program prompt me to 'pressy any key to continue'?

Tags: c++

I am trying to copy data from a webpage into an array of structs and sort by "name" before producing the data. When I run this program it says press any key to continue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct productJewelry
{
      string name;
      double amount;
      int itemCode;
      double size;
      string group;    
};

int main()
{
  // declare variables
  ifstream inFile;
      int count=0;
      int x=0;

      productJewelry product[50];

  inFile.open("jewelry.txt");  // file must be in same folder
if (inFile.fail())
 cout << "failed";
  cout << fixed << showpoint;  // fixed format, two decimal places
  cout << setprecision(2);

  while (inFile.peek() != EOF)
  {
//         cout << count << " : ";
         count++;
         inFile>> product[x].itemCode;
         inFile>> product[x].name;
         inFile>> product[x].size;
         inFile>> product[x].amount;
         inFile>> product[x].group;
//         cout << product[x].itemCode << ", " << product[x].name << ", "<< product[x].size << ", " << product[x].amount << endl;
         x++;
         if (inFile.peek() == '\n')
           inFile.ignore(1, '\n');
  }

  inFile.close();
string temp;
bool swap;
       do
         {
           swap = false;
           for (int x=0; x<count;x++)
           {
             if (product[x].name>product[x+1].name)
             {
               //these 3 lines are to swap elements in array
               temp=product[x].name;
               product[x].name=product[x+1].name;
               product[x+1].name=temp;
               swap=true;
             }
           }
         } while (swap);

      for (x=0; x< count; x++)
      {
         //cout<< product[x].itemCode<<" ";
         //cout<< product[x].name <<" ";
         //cout<< product[x].size <<" ";
         //cout<<  product[x].amount<<" ";
         //cout<<  product[x].group<<" "<<endl;

      }

  system("pause");  // to freeze Dev-c++ output screen
  return 0;
}   // end main
```

Comment: This code does **nothing** with webpages. It reads "jewelry" data from a file and sorts it by name. The line `system("pause");` makes the program wait for a keypress before exiting.

Comment: yyes it reads jewelry data and sorts it.. however, when it is compiled and ran nothing shows up besides press any key to continue

Comment: What results are you expecting? Your question need to be updated with more information.

Comment: for the c++ to print the jewelry data file and have it sorted in alphabetical order.......

Answer (score 2):

It says "press any key to continue" because that's what the `pause` program invoked by `system("pause")` does.

It doesn't output anything else because **you've commented out all of the output statements**.